# Class Template Specialization for all Classes in a Namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to specialize the class template taking a single parameter for
classes in a second library. **The first library (Poco) is given**, but the
classes in the second library can be modified.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace FirstLibrary {
    template <typename T>
    struct TypeHandler
    {
        static void apply() {
            std::cout << "First Library" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

namespace  SecondLibrary {
    template <typename T>
    struct TypeHandler {
        static void apply() {
            std::cout << "Second Library" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    struct Type {};
}


namespace FirstLibrary {
    // This is invalid code:
    // template <typename T>
    // struct TypeHandler<T> : SecondLibrary::TypeHandler<T>
    // {};

    // This is valid and suggested code I like to avoid typing over and over again:
    template<>
    struct TypeHandler<SecondLibrary::Type> : SecondLibrary::TypeHandler<SecondLibrary::Type>
    {};
}


int main() {
    FirstLibrary::TypeHandler<SecondLibrary::Type>::apply();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save some typing, you may use `using` as:

```
namespace FirstLibrary {
    // use the one you prefer:
    using SecondLibrary::Type;
    //using namespace SecondLibrary;


    template<>
    struct TypeHandler<Type> : SecondLibrary::TypeHandler<Type>
    {};
}
```

`SecondLibrary::TypeHandler` has to be specified, else `TypeHandler` will refer to `FirstLibrary::TypeHandler`.

A similar approach is to use *namespace alias*:

```
namespace FirstLibrary {
    namespace SL = SecondLibrary;

    template<>
    struct TypeHandler<SL::Type> : SL::TypeHandler<SL::Type>
    {};
}
```